# Изменение выделения секции в QTimeEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть класс, наследник от `QTimeEdit`.
Его стандартное поведение таково, что когда кликаешь двойным щелчком мыши по секции, то секция выделяется, а курсор сдвигается в конец секции (как на картинке). Мне нужно чтобы при двойном клике по секции, секция также выделялась, но курсор вставал в начало секции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал сдвигать курсор вот таким образом:

```
const auto lineedit = lineEdit();
connect(lineedit, &QLineEdit::selectionChanged, [this, lineedit]()
{
    const auto hasSelectedText = lineedit->hasSelectedText();
    if (hasSelectedText)
    {
        lineedit->cursorBackward(true, lineedit->selectionLength());
    }
});
```

курсор свдигается, но выделение с секции сбрасывается. Хотя в документации написано, что символы добавляются к выделенным.

Версия Qt `5.12.4`

Comment: Укажите версию Qt с помощью нужной метки и отформатируйте код